# using a possessive pronoun in a cleft sentence

Tags: possessive-pronouns

I'd like to know if "their" in the cleft sentence below can refer to "every businessman" in the last part of the sentence.
Can possessive pronouns only refer to certain nouns in the previous sentence or the front part of the sentence?

> It's the confidential information through **their** network tie that can
> yield profits for every businessman.

Comment: Yes, "their" clearly refers to "every business person". The sentence as a whole suggests either that the **confidential information...** is the only thing that can yield profits, or that in the greater context of this sentence, it's being compared to something that cannot yield profits. Not sure if that's the intent.

Comment: Also, "ties" rather than "tie" would be correct, and if you wouldn't mind formatting the example sentence as a quote by adding a ">" in front of it, it would be an easier read for us :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pronouns (including possessive pronouns) can refer to nouns that haven't yet been used, but it's often confusing.

I would reword this sentence to be "Every business person profits from confidential information through their network tie."

Comment: I agree - this usage might be allowed, but it's ugly and confusing in this context.